# Url.ActionLink returns wrong date format

Tags: datetime, .net-core, actionlink

I have set global date format in

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
            CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo
            {
                ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
                LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                DateSeparator = "-"
            };
            culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;
            CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                culture
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(
                new RequestLocalizationOptions
                {
                    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture),
                    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
                }
                );
...
}
```

but

```
Url.ActionLink("Index", "Show", model)
```

returns string with date like 'date=23%2F01%2F2024%2000%3A00%3A00'

How to fix it to return 'date=2024-01-23'?